# What are the best ways to check that my new laptop is genuine?

Tags: windows-10, acer-aspire, windows-genuine-advantage

I just bought a new Acer Predator Helios 300 from a 3rd party online seller.

I got 10 days of replacement warranty.

Now, as I have invested a great amount of money in this system, I just want to make sure that I got the right product.

Can anyone please help me with few of the questions that I have.

1. **How can I check that the product is genuine or refurbished or a duplicate one?**
2. **What are the ways to verify all the hardware is working fine and there is no issue with the machine?**

When I was doing R&D on this topic, I found few articles – listing them here for reference:

- http://www.notebookreview.com/howto/how-to-unbox-and-quality-check-a-new-laptop/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Best solution is to buy from a reputable dealer or right from Acer website.

Comment: I Agree, but sometimes there are factors affecting like location, cost etc. so we have to choose 3rd party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You could find the product ID/serial number, and contact Acer.

2) I would do a Prime95 CPU test to make sure it doesn't BSOD/crash/hang. I would also do a Memtest to check the RAM is ok, probably a 4-8hr soak test. You could also run some GPU benchmarks to make sure there's no artifacting on the video output.